# Assigning javascript variable to java variable

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I know I can't use `javascript` variable inside `java` code so can anyone explain me what I can do instead?

```
    function init(srcc) {
<%if (session.getAttribute("status") != null && session.getAttribute("status").equals("member")) {%>
    alert(srcc + " ");
<%application.setAttribute(session.getAttribute("currentuser"), srcc);%>
<%}%>
```

in this line:

```
 <%application.setAttribute(session.getAttribute("currentuser"), srcc);%>
```

I can't read the `srcc` variable as it's assigned in `javascript`, this function called when I press a button in `jquery`, code:

```
var $lightbox = $("<div class='lightbox'></div>");
var $img = $("<img>");
var $caption = $("<p class='caption'></p>");
var $btn = $("<div align='center'> <INPUT TYPE='BUTTON' VALUE='Add to cart'></div>");
$lightbox.append($img).append($caption).append($btn);
$('body').append($lightbox);
$('.gallery li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var src = $(this).children('img').attr("src");
    var cap = $(this).children('img').attr("alt");
    $btn.off('click').on('click', function(da) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            init(src);
        });
    });
    $img.attr('src', src);
    $caption.text(cap);
    $lightbox.fadeIn('fast');
    $lightbox.click(function() {
        $lightbox.fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

I use it in an "add to cart" button, I want the server to keep data of whom added it to the cart and what he added. (`srcc` equals what he added and `session.getAttribute("currentuser")` is whom added).
Thanks guys.

Comment: Send the variable from JavaScript to Java using an AJAX request?

Comment: @leroydev what's that? never studied it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send that JavaScript variable to Java using an [AJAX request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

You would have to have a serverside route set up to handle this request coming in and process the sent data.

Since I already see jQuery being used in your code, I'll use [this AJAX function](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) in my example code. You can send an HTTP request without your browser reloading the page in this way:

```
$.get("/urlOfCartHandler/?parameterName=" + javaScriptVariableContainingDataYouWantToSend, function(data) {
    //Request was a success
}).fail(function() {
    //Request failed
});
```